# Reinstalling/ un-revoking digital certificate

Tags: windows-vista, digital-certificate

So I have a problem in Vista which I can't run certain applications (well, the entier MS suite, Office, Visual Studio, etc) as an Administrator.

From the looks of the problem it is caused by the Digital Certificate, and the fact that it has been "revoked".

So now I have a problem, how do I un-revoke the digital certificate? Alternatively I've got a copy of the digital certificate from a co-worker whos one is fine. I've tried right-click -> install certificate but it doesn't seem to change anything, nor can I work out how to select it when I try to install a certificate for Visual Studio/ Office.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be very very surprised if Microsoft's code-signing certificate had been revoked.

I would first check your system's date and time, to ensure that Windows doesn't think the certificate isn't yet valid or has expired. Then I'd check that you still have the Microsoft Root Certificate Authority root certificate.

**UPDATE 2013-05-23**: Microsoft have in fact shipped some components whose digital signatures were not properly timestamped, meaning that they won't install properly after the certificate has expired. See [Microsoft Security Advisory 2749655 - Compatibility Issues Affecting Signed Microsoft Binaries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/security/advisory/2749655) for more information.